# VBA Copy Sheets and 1 Named Sheet to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a bit stumped.
I have a workbook that holds a series of charts.
I've had feedback that they would like an additional sheets with an explanation on how to read the charts.
My current code exports all the sheet, but now I need to update it to copy 2 sheets.
EG The automatically generated sheets, and named sheets.
I want the new workbook to include Sheet 1 and 10, then another workbook to be sheet 2 and 10, then sheet 3 and 10 etc.
Help appreciated.

```
Sub CreateReports()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim shp As Shape
Dim pf As PivotField

Sheets("Source Data").Select

Columns("E").Replace What:="YES", Replacement:="Completed", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False
Columns("E").Replace What:="No", Replacement:="Not Completed", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False

Sheets("Main Pivot").Select

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

'Create Division Sheets
On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MainPivot").ShowPages PageField:= _
        "User Custom Fields.Division2023"
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MainPivot").ShowPages PageField:= _
        "User Custom Fields.Department2023"
        
'UnProtect Sheet
Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
        
'Loop Through
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
'Hide Top Row
'ws.Rows(1).Hidden = True
'Create Chart
On Error Resume Next
Set pt = ws.PivotTables(1)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not pt Is Nothing Then
    Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(216, xlBarClustered)
    With shp.Chart
        On Error Resume Next
        .SetSourceData pt.TableRange2
        .ShowAllFieldButtons = False
        .SeriesCollection("Not Completed").Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .SeriesCollection("Completed").Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .SeriesCollection("Not Completed").DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .SeriesCollection("Completed").DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1
        .SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCenter)
    End With
    Set pt = Nothing
End If


On Error Resume Next

With ws.PivotTables(1)
  .EnableDrilldown = True
  .EnableFieldList = False
  .EnableFieldDialog = False
  .PivotCache.EnableRefresh = False
  For Each pf In .PivotFields
    With pf
      .DragToPage = False
      .DragToRow = False
      .DragToColumn = False
      .DragToData = False
      .DragToHide = False
    End With
 Next pf
End With

On Error Resume Next
Set pt = ws.PivotTables(1)
  For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
      pf.EnableItemSelection = False
  Next pf
    
'Protect Sheet
'ws.Protect Password:="Abc12345!", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, _
'UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=False, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
'AllowFormattingRows:=False, AllowInsertingColumns:=False, AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
'AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=False, AllowDeletingColumns:=False, AllowDeletingRows:=False, _
'AllowSorting:=False, AllowFiltering:=False


        
Next ws
    
Dim FPath As String
FPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & Training & "_" & ws.Name & ".xlsx"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Are those 2 new sheets present in `ThisWorkbook`? If yes, the loop you have at the end should already take care of copying them, no?

Comment: @DecimalTurn They are included in the workbook, however I have 10 worksheets. I want the new workbook to include Sheet 1 and 10, then sheet 2 and 10, then sheet 3 and 10 etc. That's the part I can't work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this where `"ExplanationSheet"` is the name of your explanation sheet:

```vb
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name <> "ExplanationSheet" Then
        Dim MySheets As Sheets
        Set MySheets = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(ws.Name, "ExplanationSheet"))
        MySheets.Copy
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & Training & "_" & ws.Name & ".xlsx"
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    End If
Next
```